# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string,when convert hours

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, casting, sql-server-2012

I get the following exception :

> conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

at this statement :

```
 select  CAST(RIGHT('0' + CAST(overtimeHours  as varchar(2)), 2) + ':00:00' As Time) 
 from #GPilot;
```

**NOTE :** this happens when `overtimeHours = 24`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because '24:00:00' is not a valid time. Use a modulo to truncate that:

```
SELECT CAST(RIGHT('0' + CAST((overtimeHours % 24) AS varchar(2)), 2) + 
  ':00:00' As Time) FROM #GPilot;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `24:00:00` hour. you should test if it's 24 and if so return `00:00:00` and add a day to the date part (if you have a date part), or change to `23:59:59`, or simply use modulo like in Amit's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31366442/3094533). The correct thing to do depends on the wider context that you didn't share in your question.